# Re-run nmap OS fingerprint match with existing subject fingerprint

Tags: nmap, network-scanners, fingerprinting, fingerprint, os-fingerprinting

I have a collection of nmap subject fingerprints (described [here](https://nmap.org/book/osdetect-fingerprint-format.html#osdetect-fp-format)), but have updated my local (private) reference fingerprint database since they were collected. Is there any existing way to re-match these subject fingerprints against the updated database without requiring a complete new scan? I've searched the nmap source code and haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a public tool to do this, but you can cobble one together pretty easily with a few functions from `osscan.cc`:

1. Load the fingerprints from `nmap-os-db` with `parse_fingerprint_file`.
2. Parse the observed fingerprint you want to test with `parse_single_fingerprint`.
3. Check for a match with `match_fingerprint`.
4. Print the results.